# differentiability of $|x|^\alpha f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $\alpha>0,\beta\ge 0$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continous and differentiable with $f(0)=\beta$ , if $g(x)=|x|^\alpha f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ then :

$\begin{align} &1) \; \alpha=1,\beta=1 && 2)\; 0\lt\alpha\lt 1 , \beta=0 \\ &3)\; \alpha\ge 1 ,\beta=0 && 4) \; \alpha\gt 0,\beta\gt 0 \end{align}$

So I tried that $D(f,0+) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}x^{\alpha-1}\beta = 0 \quad\text{Only if }\alpha\ge 1$

The same goes for the left hand derivative. So C seems reasonable but why should $\beta=0$ be the case. Am I right? What must be the correct option ? I am stuck at this point.

Comment: If $\alpha=1$, then the last limit goes to $\beta$. So that limit is zero when $\beta=0$.